# How to get time series through WebSocket from predix?

Tags: java, websocket, time-series, consumer, predix

Currently, I'm trying to get time series data for consumers. It is necessary to receive data through WebSocket, unfortunately, I don't know how to do it.

I use java's [timeseries-bootstrap](https://github.com/PredixDev/timeseries-bootstrap) for sending data to time series through WebSocket and it looks fine.

Could you kindly tell whether it is possible to receive data for consumers through a WebSocket connection? Could you provide some examples?

I would be grateful for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Predix Timeseries does not offer a websocket API for fetching data out of the datastore.  The websocket API is designed for pushing lots of data into the datastore only.  For querying data, Predix only offers a REST API.